# R sparse smoothing splines

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

I would like to fit a model of the form `weight ~ bs(height) + id`, where id is a factor (so I have several observations per every id).  There are perhaps 100k values of `id`.  Does anyone know the best way to go about fitting this?  I have tried the mgcv package, but I do not think it was designed for problems this large and sparse.  I can define my own knots and figure out the best smoothing parameter, if necessary. Also, if anyone has a solution in Python, that's great too.  Or just the right phrase to google would be helpful, also.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your problem is really to do with splines, but with fitting 100,000 degrees of freedom for `id`. Depending on what you actually want to do with it, this seems like a good situation for a random-effects model. In R, you can fit them using a variety of functions, with `lme` in package `nlme` probably being a good place to start.

Also, the GAM label usually refers to the use of *smoothing* splines, not fixed-knot splines as fit by `bs` and `ns`. If you're happy to use `bs` and its cousins, you don't need `gam`; `glm` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **mgcv** using something like this model:

```
mod <- gam(weight ~ s(height, bs = "cr") + s(id, bs = "re"), data = FOO)
```

If that is causing trouble with fitting, try `bam()` which is designed for large data sets:

```
mod <- bam(weight ~ s(height, bs = "cr") + s(id, bs = "re"), data = FOO)
```

The `bs = "re"` specifies a random effect for `id` as you might use in a mixed effects model. This exploits the close relationship between the penalised regression view of the GAM and mixed models where the some of the penalties can be viewed as random effects terms.